# Why can't I schedule a timer through a function?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, rust, timer

I am using a crate called `timer` and I'm trying to put a timer "guard" into a hashmap to store it so that I can either drop it before it ends or make sure I don't create a duplicate.

The problem is that the timer does not trigger when inserted into a hashmap **through a function**, but works fine if the body of the function is moved to `main` instead.

```
extern crate chrono;
extern crate timer;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn insert_to_guard_map(guard_map: &mut HashMap<i32, timer::Guard>) {
    let timer = timer::Timer::new();
    let guard = timer.schedule_with_delay(chrono::Duration::seconds(2), || {
        println!("Called after 2s.");
    });

    guard_map.insert(42, guard);
}

fn main() {
    let mut guard_map = HashMap::new();

    insert_to_guard_map(&mut guard_map);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(4));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of [`Timer`](https://yoric.github.io/timer.rs/doc/timer/struct.Timer.html) and [`Guard`](https://yoric.github.io/timer.rs/doc/timer/struct.Guard.html) mention that if either the `Timer` or the `Guard` is dropped, then the scheduled execution is ultimately cancelled.

So in that case, either insert both the `timer` and `guard` into the [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html).

```rust
use timer::{Guard, Timer};

fn insert_to_guard_map(guard_map: &mut HashMap<i32, (Timer, Guard)>) {
    let timer = Timer::new();
    let guard = timer.schedule_with_delay(chrono::Duration::seconds(2), || {
        println!("Called after 2s.");
    });

    guard_map.insert(42, (timer, guard));
}
```

Alternatively (and likely better), pass a reference of `Timer` to `insert_to_guard_map()`.

```rust
use timer::{Guard, Timer};

fn insert_to_guard_map(guard_map: &mut HashMap<i32, Guard>, timer: &Timer) {
    let guard = timer.schedule_with_delay(chrono::Duration::seconds(2), || {
        println!("Called after 2s.");
    });

    guard_map.insert(42, guard);
}

fn main() {
    let timer = Timer::new();
    let mut guard_map = HashMap::new();

    insert_to_guard_map(&mut guard_map, &timer);
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(4));
}
```